# What journals do not allow open access to published material?

Tags: publications, journals, open-access

An increasing number of funding organizations require publications on the research that they fund to be open access, i.e. available to the public without having to subscribe to a journal or pay a fee. Does anybody know where I can find a list of journals/publishers that do not allow material that they publish to be published this way?

Comment: The question should be "where can I find a list of open access journal", as nobody will try to find a list of pay-walled journals.

Comment: Note that a vast majority of subscription-based journals comply with this requirement because they automatically post pre-prints on things like pubmed central (sometimes after an embargo), and almost all of them allow pre-prints on pre-prints servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of reputable open access journals](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/list-of-reputable-open-access-journals)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This answer to a related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/10/12) points to http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/, which allows you to look up the policy of specific journals.

Answer (score 9):

[Directory of open access journals](http://www.doaj.org/) is the most comprehensive listing for the open access ones, so if you find a journal there, it's open. If not, then you need further research. Though usually clicking on an article link should be sufficient.