# Submitting a subset of my work to ArXiv

Tags: journals, publications, science, arxiv

I've been thinking of publishing a subset of my work in fluid dynamics to arXiv. I realize the following about arXiv:

1. ArXiv isn't a journal
2. I would need to be endorsed to submit an article on arXiv

The reasons I would like to submit a subset of my work to arXiv are:

1. It would only be a subset of my work thereby NOT negating my chances of publishing work in a regular journal.
2. I would like to disseminate information to the society as soon as possible.

Does anyone have any thoughts or comments about this? Is there something that I'd need to feel uneasy about?

I realize that there has been another question regarding submission of work to arXiv and I read it [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7/does-publishing-a-paper-on-arxiv-prevent-me-to-submit-it-to-a-non-open-access-jo).

Comment: "Does anyone have any thoughts or comments about this?" is awfully open-ended.  It might help to ask something a bit more concrete.

Comment: Most journals allow publishing a manuscript that already appeared *verbatim* on arXiv, so you shouldn't worry about publishing only a subset of your work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Opinions on when to submit things to arXiv vary both between and within fields.  See

- [To Post or Not to Post: Publishing to the arXiv Before Acceptance](http://www.astrobetter.com/to-post-or-not-to-post-publishing-to-the-arxiv-before-acceptance/)
- [How to use arXiv?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73526/how-to-use-arxiv)

for lots of opinions.  You should talk to your advisor/colleagues who can give you a better sense of how people in your field think about this.