# Publishing policies for conference papers

Tags: publications, conference, copyright

I got two papers accepted and I am just wondering how to know their policy towards publishing my papers also on CoRR. is it fine to publish the same paper in CoRR and in the conference?

Comment: This is entirely a function of the publisher of the conference paper; CoRR does not impose any restrictions itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, it's fine, as long as you submit a pre-print and not the camera ready of the conf proceedings. You can also check these questions: [Does publishing a paper on arXiv prevent me from submitting it to a non-open access journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7/102) and [Submitting a subset of my work to ArXiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/40/102).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Charles's answer, it depends on how the conference papers are published. If they're published as a special issue of a journal, then it may very well depend on the policies of the journal, as well as those of the conference. (And some conferences may have special restrictions on publications; in those cases, you should check with the conference organizers.)