# Paper stolen by a co author and published as his own

Tags: research-process, undergraduate, career-path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My research work stolen and published as his own by the co author without my consent](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/975/my-research-work-stolen-and-published-as-his-own-by-the-co-author-without-my-con)

My research paper was stolen by a co-author. I have reported her but the head of my institution is defending that teacher. I have all the mail correspondences between the unethical co-author and myself along with all the data that I produced as part of my contribution.

How do I go about proving my side of defense? My faculty are trying to prove that she has done this as a part of her MTECH, which is completely false!

What do I do?

Comment: @recursion.ninja Hi. Please refrain from editing closed questions when your edit does not fix the problem related to why the question was closed in the first place.

Comment: @recursion.ninja Have a look at [this meta post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/editing-weak-questions-that-are-closed-for-being-off-topic-without-resolving-t).

Comment: @MadJack thanks for the reference. I have reviewed it and understand the community's position on such questions. I didn't know it would affect the re-open queue. Can I ask why [this revision](http://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25480) was rejected? I thought it greatly improved readability. What is the community's standards on revisions for formatting & readability?