# Arxiv equivalent for medical research article

Tags: arxiv, open-access, online-publication, preprint, medicine

I'm looking for a suggestion, for a medical journal counter part to the [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/). A minimal frill, open access online repository 
to time stamp articles with some visibility.

Comment: Given how concerned doctors can be about the risks of confusing the public by circulating papers before peer review, I doubt the medical community would support anything like the arXiv.  (But I don't know enough to give a definitive answer.)  There are certainly open access repositories for published papers, such as PubMed Central, but that's different.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician yes, as you point out that is different. The main concern here is one of claiming intellectual ownership (time stamping the research result)

Comment: You can get a time stamp with any regular blog, or sites like Researchgate. Now for visibility in medicine, you won't get much without publishing in a peer-reviewed well-ranked journal. This being said, there are medicine-related papers on the arxiv.

Comment: If it's intellectual property you're looking at, what you need is a patent.

Comment: If it's specifically the time stamp you want, rather than public visibility, see http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23367/how-can-i-time-stamp-my-data-without-publishing-it

Comment: @CapeCode no, patents do not cover all kinds of intellectual property. Papers are not patented, but subject to copyright.

Comment: @fqq yes you're right. I meant intellectual property on something they invented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**medRxiv**: a preprint server for health sciences.
https://www.medrxiv.org/

Comment: This is the correct answer today. The preprint serve medRxiv was [launched in June 2019](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01806-2), several years after the question was asked here.

Answer (score 11):

To elaborate on the answer by ddiez: [bioRxiv](http://biorxiv.org/) has been deliberately designed to fill the same sort of role for life sciences that arXiv does for physics, math, and computer science.  A key reason for this is the growing recognition amongst some practitioners in these fields that scientific communication is being inhibited by the long time to publication and pre-publication secrecy that is typical in life science fields---it is not uncommon to be hearing privately about work for years before one is able to read the details or cite it.  Overall, this is a very good thing: it improves communication, it reduces the chance of being "scooped," and it reduces the "all-or-nothing" pressure associated with targeting super-high-impact journals.

That said, bioRxiv is still fairly new, and the conventions for its relationship with journals are still evolving.  Some journals are very supportive and encourage authors to deposit in bioRxiv.  Others still tightly embrace the prior publication culture and consider deposit in a preprint repository a prior publication that precludes submission.  Check carefully what the policy of the journals that you are targeting with before you make a decision about whether to deposit.

Comment: Note that this answer has been obsoleted by the launch of medRxiv, as noted in the newer answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of a "pre-print" (I don't mean this term in a derogatory manner) repository for medical research similar to arXiv. I think there are two reasons for this. The first is that my understanding is that the peer review process in medical fields often takes less than a month and rarely more than a year where as in Physics and Maths I think the pattern is reversed. The second reason, and I believe the most important reason, is that medical research studies should be preregistered. The [2013 Declaration of Helsinki](http://www.wma.net/en/30publications/10policies/b3/index.html) states:

> Every research study involving human subjects must be registered in a publicly accessible database before recruitment of the first subject.

This requirement has lead to initiatives (or possible vice versa) of trial repositories like [bioMed Central](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/protocols) where protocols can be peer reviewed and published. While this is very different from arXiv which archives complete studies, it may provide the type of "time stamping" you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, preregistering a clinical trial doesn't mean that the trial outcomes (i.e., the resulting research paper) will be freely accessible.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the OP was not asking for open access, but rather a timestamp with some visibility.

Comment: I see. The question is a bit unclear then as currently stated imho. (I had upvoted your answer btw, it's a great one, my comment was just aimed for readers not familiar with the topic)

Answer (score 3):

The closest would be [bioRxiv](http://biorxiv.org).

Comment: This was a correct answer when the question was asked. But meanwhile [medRxiv](https://www.medrxiv.org/) was launched [in June 2019](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01806-2) - see the [answer by gncs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/145809/4141).

Answer (score 2):

How about [PeerJ Preprints](https://peerj.com/about/publications/#PeerJ-Preprints)? It was [launched](https://peerj.com/blog/post/47030855181/peerj-preprints-a-new-preprint-server-for-the-biological-and-medical-sciences/) in 2013.

> PeerJ Preprints is the 'pre-print' area of PeerJ. Similar to pre-print servers that already exist (for example arXiv.org), authors can submit draft, incomplete, or final versions of articles they are working on.
>   ...
>   PeerJ Preprints will only accept submissions in the same subject areas as PeerJ (Biological and Medical Sciences) and PeerJ Computer Science.

Answer (score 1):

## Researchgate.net

A lot of academic medical professionals are uploading pre- and post-publication manuscripts to https://www.researchgate.net/

**EDIT:** Above answer was all there was at the end of 2017. However, since June 2019, [medRxiv.org](https://www.medrxiv.org/) fully serves the needs of  the medical science community.

[image: medRxiv.org]