# Collaborator published paper on ArXiv without my name

Tags: publications, authorship, copyright, arxiv

In the last four months, I have been working on a project with a friend. After the completion of writing part of paper, I started searching for conferences and found that my friend had already submitted a previous/incomplete version of the paper on ArXiv.

Now my friend claims ownership of the idea and copyright  as it is now already  published in a pre-print. At present we both have the completed paper, codes and results. In reality, I did the most of the analysis in the project although the idea came out of discussion between us.

My friend wants to publish it on their own without giving me any credit. I even agreed  that they can be the first author, and I will be second, but they keep on insisting that they will not include me.

Even if I submit this in a conference, I am concerned that my submission will be rejected as the other author already has a proof of that work. I also hold the proof that I did the writing and computation part because most of the time I emailed them these results, but due to his cheating, I have no way to prove that I did the major work in this project. Any suggestions will be very helpful on how to tackle this problem.

Does a pre-print of the paper (containing the idea and some incomplete results) in their name, gives them an advantage if we both try to publish it?

Comment: Also, could you add what is your hope: that you get the credit that you deserve or that you can even continue a healthy working relationship with the other guy. The advice that can be given will be different in these cases.

Comment: Next time use a version control system with all documents you make. It's not at all hard to use but they provide timestamps and diff about what exactly you did, so they could constitute proof of your contribution. Using an online repository is especially good, since in this way the timestamps are given by the neutral third party. (for example bitbucket unlimited free private repositories).

Comment: @DCTLib It's already clear that the OP **doesn't** have a healthy working relationship with this person.

Comment: @Bakuriu version control systems do not provide proof of contribution.  The timestamps are not given by a third party.  You can change the time of a commit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git.  It is not too late for the OP to use a free private bitbucket repository with commits that predate the arXiv submission.

Comment: @Kimball True - I should have used the word "restore" instead of "continue".

Comment: have you contacted your university (or company's) legal department? they will have much more to say about this topic, as well as a vested interest in protecting your (and their) stake in the matter.

Comment: @emory Timestamps are not the only information contained in a version control system. The commits contain information about which files where change and **how**. Faking all of this is not a trivial task, assuming you never had a place in it, because you must find a possible logic history for the result, how it developed etc. Moreover I'm pretty sure bitbucket keeps track of their *server time* (i.e. a 3rd party time) when you access your repositories to perform push/pull moreover such services do periodic backups, so you could ask bitbucket if their backup from 1 month ago contained the repo.

Comment: I would say that the fact that your collaborator has published the paper as a pre-print should not change whether you can prove anything about it or your participation in it. It may make it more difficult to convince other people of it, though, but convincing people and being able to prove something is (at least in theory) to very different things.

Comment: "My friend wants to publish it on their own without giving me any credit. I even agreed that they can be the first author, and I will be second, but they keep on insisting that they will not include me." -- Sorry, I am not sure *how many* are your "friends" in this conflict from reading this paragraph. I think this is an important point.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> […] he claims that the idea belongs to him and he also has copyright for it as he already has published a pre-print for it.

Publishing content does not give you copyright for it; creating content does¹. There are exceptions if you sign over your copyright, but that would involve an actual contract, which I assume not to be the case here.

If you wrote parts of the paper or generated figures, publishing the paper without your name and consent is a copyright infringement. Hence, if you have proof of this, you have a legal case against your “friend”.

Moreover, publishing this paper as a sole author and thus denying you authorship constitutes a severe academic misconduct, which may very well end your “friend”’s academic career if you can convincingly prove it.

> Any suggestion will be very helpful on how to tackle this problem.

Collect and secure all evidence that you contributed to the project, in particular any statement from your “friend” that implies this. Get a [time stamp](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23367/7734) for the full paper as soon as possible.

Assuming that you do not want to or gave up to save your relationship, take the issue to a relevant authority, e.g., your advisor, your “friend”’s advisor, your university’s legal department, the ethics board, or similar. The best choice here depends on the detailed situation and relationships. For example, if you are both students under different supervisors who are friendly with each other, I would take it to your supervisor first.

You might also be able to take the issue to the ArXiv. I am not sure about their protocol for such cases and whether they have any, but I do not expect that they will just leave the paper as it is if you can convince them that you are a worthy co-author.

> Does a preprint of the paper (contains the idea and some results,not the complete one) in his name, gives him an advantage if we both try to publish it?

If you fail to convince others of your authorship claims, yes.

---

<sup>¹ In any reasonable legislation and in particular every legislation that complies with international copyright conventions.</sup>

Comment: Regarding the arXiv issue--it's not clear from the question if the original arXiv post was entirely the friend's work or not. @Virange, perhaps clarify?

Comment: @Kimball: From the original version of the question: “[…] when I start searching for the conferences, I came to know that the other guy had already submitted a previous/uncompleted version of the paper on arxiv.”; from the current version “I started searching for conferences and found that the other guy had already submitted a previous/uncompleted version of the paper on ArXiv” – I consider this a clear statement of the asker that he was not involved in the ArXiv submission.

Comment: Yes, it's clear the OP wasn't involved in the arXiv submission.  Though I wasn't sure if the arXiv submission happened _before_ the OP started collaborating on this project.  (It's unclear if they started the project together, or the OP joined an ongoing project, though upon rereading the second paragraph of the question, I guess the arXiv submission happened after they started working together.)

Comment: Excellent advice. Use your (and his) supervisor as leverage.

Comment: @Kimball: We both started working together as I mentioned that the idea came from our discussions. He submitted a previous version of paper which I wrote initially just to include broad idea and some results.

Comment: @Virange Then you should definitely look into having the arXiv paper retracted.  Gather your evidence and  [contact the moderators](http://arxiv.org/help/moderation).