How would someone submit a proposed proof of a Creator of the universe theory for peer review
B"H
I'm aware of this question Getting peer review for research without submitting to conference or journal
Which asks specifically for what platforms are good for submitting a study for peer review, but how would one go about submitting a proposed proof of the Creator to get credible critique from professionals, and/or published in some kind of scientific journal?
As opposed to that question, I'm asking for any way to give legitimate professional authentication to the proposed study, including publication.
What category would this fall under, and what journals or professionals would be open to peer reviewing it? I'm asking about only cheap reviews, under $50, but still credible.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/201589/how-can-an-independent-researcher-publish-a-well-written-research-paper-proof Similar to this, you write it up and submit it to a journal.

The thing about peer review is not to give your work credibility. It is to critique and assess the methodology you use. As a consequence, if you submit your proposed work to peer review, you will also have to live with the fact that it may be negative. You can't just use review "to give legitimate professional authentication" to your study -- you will in all likelihood get reviews that say "this is unscientific".
As a separate matter, $50 equates to perhaps 20-30 minutes of a typical researcher's time, if you take into account the salary, health and retirement benefits, and self-employment taxes. You won't get respectable researchers to read through a 20- or 30-page paper for that amount.
