# When can I safely use CC-BY license on arXiv?

Tags: publications, arxiv, open-access, open-science, creative-commons

On [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) one can license a preprint on one of the following (see also [a note on arXiv on licenses](http://arxiv.org/help/license)):

- [arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license to distribute this article](http://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/license.html) (Minimal rights required by arXiv.org. Select this unless you understand the implications of other licenses.)
- [Creative Commons Attribution license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)
- [Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-ShareAlike license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
- [Creative Commons Public Domain Declaration](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/)

For cases when it is fine to submit a paper on *arXiv.org perpetual* (see also [Does publishing a paper on arXiv prevent me from submitting it to a non-open access journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7/does-publishing-a-paper-on-arxiv-prevent-me-from-submitting-it-to-a-non-open-acc)), when I can safely use **CC-BY** (Creative Commons Attribution license)?

Ideally, I would use it all the time, as it is the most permissible (=open) license, which requires attribution. (However, [I used it only once](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1031), it a case where I don't intend to send it to a journal; so, except for that case, when one should (or shouldn't) be afraid of using CC-BY on arXiv?)

EDIT: Here the emphasis is on **arXiv perpetual** vs **CC**, not on choosing between CC licenses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a **CC-BY** license on arxiv.org will be fine whenever you don't need to retain exclusive rights. **CC-BY** is a non-exclusive license, and you are free to grant as many non-exclusive licenses as you wish. However, you won't be able to grant a exclusive license thereafter, which is what most commercial publishers are looking for. The typical "*transfer of copyright*" would essentially be an exclusive license in these cases.

If you intend to publish the paper submitted to arxiv.org with an open access publisher, it should generally work with a CC-BY license. Most open access publishers require only a non-exclusive license to publish a paper, so there would be no conflict here. It may however not be possible to go to a publisher which requires either an exclusive license or a copyright transfer afterwards.

Interestingly, a copyright transfer may be less restrictive than an exclusive license in this case. In principle, it should be possible to transfer copyright even if a license have already been granted to someone else (that's how a company would buy software from another company that has already been licensed). So, why not try the following with your next paper:

1. Submit it to arxiv under a CC-BY license.
2. Submit to a commercial publisher, and add a statement like this to the copyright transfer agreement:

> "This agreement is with the understanding that a non-revocable, non-exclusive license under the terms CC-BY has been granted to a arxiv.org."

I wonder how they'd react...

Comment: I wouldn't try using a CC license and then submitting unless you are seriously willing to find another journal if it doesn't work (since it may very well not work). Also, even non-profit publishers often ask for terms in compatible with some or all CC licenses.

Comment: There is at least one case of ACM dropping a paper from a proceedings replacing it with a one-line note linking to the arXiv copy in this case. See: http://r6.ca/blog/20110930T012533Z.html

Comment: @MikaelVejdemo-Johansson Thanks for the link. I can understand that they like public domain even less than CC-BY...

Comment: A "transfer of copyright" is completely different from an exclusive license, and I am not aware of any reason why you cannot perform a typical academic copyright after having made the document available under an open licence.  BTW, I have performed steps 1 and 2 on every paper I've submitted and I only have ever had trouble with the ACM because they have an on-line only copyright transfer form.

Comment: @RussellO'Connor In my view, transfer of copyright and exclusive license are equivalent. In my case, I can't even transfer copyright (it's a non-transferable right where I live). I don't have an explicit source know, but I remember publishers claiming that when I sign a copyright transfer agreement, it's essentially equivalent to an exclusive license for me. And the key point is that you cannot give an exclusive license after you gave a non-exclusive one, such as CC-BY.

Comment: Note that "transfer of copyright" is not even a thing in some jurisdictions (e.g. in Germany). If German researchers sign something like this for US publishers, afaik, the passage is void.

Comment: @Raphael I don't think it's void. AFAIK it would be interpreted as granting an exclusive license, which you can do also under German copyright.

Comment: Certainly. It's not quite the same, though.

Comment: Does anything in this answer change if the default "arXiv perpetual" license is chosen instead of CC? The "arXiv perpetual" license is also a non-exclusive license.

Comment: @wimi in principle I think it would be the same, but if publishers explicitly state that prior submission to arXiv is ok then I would interpret that in the sense that they are ok with authors having granted arXiv a license to publish the paper. That may even be part of what is usually called "retained rights" in the copyright transfer.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to know except by checking with the journals you have in mind. In mathematics, almost all journals will be OK with the default arXiv license, but most of them have copyright terms that would be incompatible with the CC licenses. Some may make an exception for you, but I would guess that many commercial journals would not (and probably some non-commercial ones, too - for example, the ACM is not friendly towards this sort of thing). Because this would often involve an exception to posted policies, I don't think there's any way to find out systematically besides asking individually. They may also be reluctant to make any general statements that could be interpreted as a precedent.

So in mathematics, I would be wary of the CC options unless you are sure you will submit only to the minority of journals that allow this. (And, of course, you should never choose any license without agreement from all coauthors.)

Comment: I never saw a statement explicitly allowing using a CC license (except for case when a journal publishes on such license)

Comment: I've never seen it explicitly mentioned, but some copyright forms for free journals are compatible with CC BY (e.g., http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/about/submissions#copyrightNotice). Aside from these cases, which you can determine by reading the copyright form carefully, or journals that use CC licenses themselves, you would have to ask for an exception.

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised at a math journal overruling the decisions of their editorial board over copyright concerns.  But at any rate, it's the acceptance that matters, not the publication.  I'd be happy to list a paper as accepted on my CV in this situation.

Comment: I don't think it would be looked at as overruling the editorial board.  The acceptance is always conditional on dealing with the copyright issues, and if the author is unable to do so then the acceptance is moot (and might be officially rescinded, depending on the publisher's policies, which would complicate listing it on a CV - at the very least the wording would have to be very careful).  Furthermore, I'd bet many editorial boards would be unsympathetic.

Comment: In my experience, editors often push publishers to give authors reasonable rights, but not necessarily everything they ask for, and I've also seen boards push demanding authors to compromise regarding copyright issues.  If an author declares "It's too late; I've already released the paper under CC BY so your only option is to agree to everything", then some editors would be annoyed and view the author as acting in bad faith.  Other editors might be sympathetic, but it would be difficult to convince the full board to stand up for the principle that authors must be allowed to use CC BY licenses.

Comment: The principle isn't that authors must be allowed to use CC BY licenses (personally I don't, as the arXiv's default license seems to cover the rights that I want), but rather that acceptance decisions should be made for mathematical reasons and not corporate reasons.  As far as quality of theorem is concerned, everything after acceptance is irrelevant.