# What license should be chosen on arXiv for a paper to be published in Communications in Algebra at Taylor&Francis?

Tags: publications, mathematics, arxiv, license

I have never been submitting the paper to arXiv so I have a question about
what kind of license or declaration I must choose to be able to submit the expanded version of the manuscript, which is soon to be accepted in Communications in Algebra at Taylor&Francis. My worry is about the Copyright agreement I will sign with Taylor&Francis.

The options on the arXiv are as follows:

- arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license to distribute this article (Minimal rights required by arXiv.org)
- Creative Commons Attribution license (CC BY 4.0)
- Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license (CC BY-SA 4.0)
- Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-ShareAlike license (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0)
- Creative Commons Public Domain Declaration (CC0 1.0)
- None of the above licenses apply.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at other works that were published in both arXiv and that journal to see what the appropriate license might be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the publisher's rules](https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/sharing-your-work/), you can share your preprint "as much as you like". According to [SHERPA/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/search.php?issn=0092-7872), you can also share the post-refereed version. What you cannot share is the publisher's version, the one that will appear on the website (don't ask me why).

So the simplest and safest is probably the first option, grant arXiv a license to distribute your article. [You can find more info here.](https://arxiv.org/help/license) Roughly speaking, with the CC licenses, you allow other people to take your article, redistribute it themselves, modify it and redistribute the modified version etc., possibly with some limitations (SA: they must use the same license when redistributing; NC: commercial use is prohibited). [It appears possible that the CC licenses conflict with copyright transfers.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9740/when-can-i-safely-use-cc-by-license-on-arxiv?rq=1)

I've never tried, but if you check the last option ("none of the above licenses apply") then arXiv will probably refuse your preprint. The "public domain" option is also probably not possible for you, because that would mean you waive all your copyright-related rights, including transferring the copyright to the publisher – which they will probably require.

Comment: I've used CC0 and then the publisher (Springer) gave me a special publishing agreement to sign that didn't include assigning copyright to them. The academic editors of the journal had accepted the paper after all...

Comment: @DavidRoberts Well, that's a bet you can choose to take. Given the pain of the review process, I don't really want to waste all this time because of a technicality (imagine they had refused).

Comment: then I would have posted the acceptance letter from the editor(s) with the paper on the arXiv and made public noise about how the publisher refused to negotiate with me. I will admit one cannot attempt this if the conditions for submitting are so stringent as to forbid any kind of licensing prior to publication.