# Do all licenses in arxiv have no ban

Tags: arxiv

Is there a license from one of the five or six licenses that has a ban period, mean, they delete your article after a while, or all licenses do not have a ban

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104722/what-license-should-be-chosen-on-arxiv-for-a-paper-to-be-published-in-communicat - I don't believe any of them delete the article.

Comment: If you give them a perpetual license to distribute, then they can do so forever. But it doesn't _require_ them to do so forever. What is your actual concern here?